# Global sidebar with widget support

Tags: layout, zend-framework2

I would like to make a layout with a sidebar that can have widgets from different modules. Lets say there shall always be a login widget at the top if the user isn't logged in then it shall show user info. The [getting started album guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html) could use it to display the latest albums and so on, i hope you understand how i want to use the sidebar.

Could it be done with a config file in autoload and a small code that read that config and calls the widgets on every page load?

Comment: [View helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html)?

Comment: Sry, to lazy for an answer, this will help though: http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/

Comment: Thanks Sam that solved it all for me! To bad i can't accept this as a answer.

Comment: ok, this is great but... is any easy and flexible way to put forms in widgets? of course i can put "normal" form with target on dedicated controller/action and comeback to source page using http_reffer but in this approach i dont have for example validation errors on source page.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of page composition in Zend Framework 2:

### 1. Switching between Layouts

By default, ZF2 provides you with a single layout template *layout.phtml*.
In real-life applications, you will probably need to have several layouts
and switch the layout for certain controller/action. In each of your layouts, you will be able to show different widgets/sidebars.

### 2. Partial Views

A *partial* view is a *.phtml* view template file which can be rendered by another 
view template. Partial views allow to compose your page of pieces and reuse pieces 
of view rendering logic across different view templates. This is accomplished through the `Partial` view helper.

### 3. Placeholder View Helper

The `Placeholder` is another useful view helper allowing for capturing HTML 
content and storing it for later use. Thus, analogous to the `Partial` 
view helper, it allows to compose your page of several pieces.

### 4. Forward Controller Plugin

With the `Forward` controller plugin, you are able to call an action (for example, the action rendering some widget) from another module/controller from your controller and grab the output of that action. Then you are able to incorporate that output into your page.

### 5. Use View Models for Page Composition

When you write action methods for the controller classes, you use the `ViewModel`
class as a variable container for passing the variables from controller to view template,
and for overriding the default view template name. But, actually the `ViewModel` class is more than just a variable container plus view template name. In fact, it is closely related to the layout and page composition.

The third big capability of the view model class is that it allows for *combining* several 
view models in a tree-like structure. Each view model in the tree has the associated
view template name and data variables that can be passed to the view template to control
the process of rendering.

This feature is internally used by Zend Framework 2 when "combining" the layout view template and the view template associated with the controller's action method. ZF2 internally creates the view model for the layout template and assigns it with `layout/layout` view template name. When your controller's action method returns the `ViewModel` object, this object is attached as a child to the layout view model.

So, you can attach your own view models to the default view model to render the page of pieces that you want.